# Pandas for loop on index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, normalization

I have a pandas dataframe that is indexed by some **non-unique** non-contiguous id numbers.

```
x
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'  
Int64Index: 814061 entries, 8536896 to 8498857  
Data columns (total 1 columns):  
received    814061  non-null values  
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
```

x['received'] are timestamps that aren't all the same length.

```
x.ix[i] might have len() == 20  
x.ix[j] might have len() == 32.
```

for any x.ix[i] I can fit the timestamps into a [0,1] range with

```
df['totalseconds'] = x.ix[i]['received']-x.ix[i]['received'].min()
y = x.ix[i]['received'].max()-x.ix[i]['received'].min()
z = timedelta.total_seconds(y)
df['seconds'] = df['totalseconds'].apply(lambda x: x / timedelta64(1, 's'))
df['norm'] = df['seconds']/z
```

I am trying to normalize my timeperiods for each index in x. But am having trouble for some reason.

tldr; How do I get all my timestamps into a [0, 1] range, by index id?

Comment: slightly confused, how do you have a unique index, a dtype of datetime64[ns] *and* have x.ix[scalar] return different length objects? Maybe you mean a groupby operation? (if so, nice to post that)

Comment: `np.shape(x) = (814061, 1)` & `len(x.ix[8498857]['received']) = 2` & `len(x.ix[8536896]['received']) = 3`  **The index is only 100 unique numbers of different length timestamps**  If that helps.

Comment: `x.ix[8536896]['received'] = 2013-09-09 16:27:54, 2013-09-09 17:56:15, 2013-09-09 15:01:35` and I want to normalize to [0, 1] start and stop for all indices.

Comment: I tried groupby but I can't get it to work. `key = lambda x: x.index`  `seconds = lambda x: (x['received'] - x['received'].min())/(x['received'].max() - x['received'].min())` `x['norm'] = x.groupby(key).transform(seconds)` gives me an AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: I think `x['norm'] = x.groupby(x['received']).transform(seconds)` is almost correct. It gives Error: can only operate on a timedeltas for addition and subtraction, but the operator [__truediv__] was passed.  However, when I try to use `timedelta.total_seconds` I get TypeError: descriptor 'total_seconds' requires a 'datetime.timedelta' object but received a 'function'